# Reversing order of two items in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an sql query that returns the field presenters as a single array for each presenter (there can be several) :

```
[Doe, Jane undefined] => Array
    (
        [middle_name] => 
        [department] => Leadership Studies
        [institution] => Any State University
        [city] => Dayton
        [state] => Oh
        [country] => United States
        [office_phone] => 123-45-7896
        [cell_phone] => 
        [email_address] => John.doe@anywhere.edu
        [website] => 
    )
)
```

I then do this:

```
 $cleanpresenters = parse_ini_string($data['presenters'],TRUE);
    foreach ($cleanpresenters as $name=>$val1) 
    {
    $name = trim($name);
    $presenters[] = $name;
    $convertedpresenters .= "$name \n {$val1['department']}, {$val1['institution']}\n";
    };
    $finalpresenters = str_replace("undefined","", $convertedpresenters);
```

which returns a nice clean:
Doe, Jane
Leadership Studies, Any State University

My question: is there anyway to reverse the name and get Jane Doe  -minus the comma? 
Thanks!

Comment: $temp = explode(",", $name);     $convertedpresenters .= "$temp[1] $temp[0]  \n {$val1['department']}, {$val1['institution']}\n";

Comment: Would like to give the answer to Rsauxil since he was first, but not sure how since his answer was a comment.  Thanks to both of you!  It works!

Comment: Doesn't matter, I gave a very, very basic solution, so I thought it was not worth making up a whole post for it, the method of Noah is also cleaner, so he deserves the credit ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newName = implode(" ", array_map("trim", array_reverse(explode(",", $name))))
```

That should do the magic for you

EDIT:

- explode() separates the string into an array, based on the comma delimiter
- array_reverse() reverses the direction of the array
- array_map() is used to trim every element in the array
- implode() brings the array back to a string, separating each element by a space